# How to save a treeview selected node when I pressed a Tab key?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a treeview control. I use keyboard to navigate through nodes. I want to save a SelectedNode when I pressed a TAB key. How ?

"Save" : I mean it makes a selectednode == null when I press TAB key. I want that selected node still remains selected even if I pressed a TAB key inside treeview control.

C#, WinForms, 3.5, VS 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `HideSelection` property of the treeview control to *false*.